# laravel installer - requirements could not be resolved

Tags: laravel, composer-php

```
Problem 1
 -laravel/installer v1.1.1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[...]

 -guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.2.3 requires php>=5.4.0 -> no matching package found
```

I am using vagrant ( hashicorp/precise32 )

I used this to try and install the laravel installer

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the error message carefully and you have the problem:

Laravel installer requires guzzlehttp/guzzle. Guzzle requires php >= 5.4.0 (greater than or equal to version 5.4.0). This was not found.

In other words, you do not meet the PHP requirement (you'll properbly use PHP 5.3.x)

Comment: you are right - I assumed I had installed the latest version of php since I am running this on vagrant. thank you.